# Binding arraylist to grid view (Part whatever....)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding

Ok, I'me getting real dumb with this one....

I have this class:

```
Public Class whatever
Public id as string
Public name as string
public date as string
end class
```

Wich I use with this code:

```
dim personlist as new arraylist

dim person as new whatever
person.id="1"
person.name="bozo"
person.date="6-6-6"
personlist.add(person)
```

and then i repeat so that i can fill my arraylist with all the information that I want to show in my gridview.

The problem is this:

```
gridview1.datasource = personlist
gridview1.databind()
```

When executing, I get an error saying :

```
The data source for GridView with id 'gdpersonlist' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.
```

Can anyone help me or perhaps point me in the right direction to do this?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using properties instead of fields.  The data binding for the grid view won't work for fields.

```
Public Class whatever
  Public _id as string
  Public name as string
  public date as string

  Public Property Id As String 
    Get 
      Return _id
    End Get
    Set (value as String )
      _id = value
    End Set
  End Property

  ' repeat for all 3 fields
end class
```